# Compilation from source for QGIS 2.2.0 in OpenSuse

Tags: linux, qgis-2.2

Someone can help me for installing from source QGIS valmiera 2.2 on linux OpenSuse 12.2.

I needed of understand the library and relative version of a tested enviroment.

The version of OpenSuse is not influent but I needed to use valmiera 2.2 version.